# LogLikelihood[MultinomialDistribution[],{}] Not working?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
LogLikelihood[MultinomialDistribution[100, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5}], {{10, 20, 70}}]
```

> -12.8338

No problem at all.

```
n = 171
pj = {0.5678342897940185`, 0.05023062094430643`, 
  0.029299646238927373`, 0.023714945004969255`, 0.022954135971897396`,
   0.02636142850073763`, 0.04033297983450963`, 0.23927195371850615`}
Tr[pj] (* check probabilities sum to 1 *)
data = {3, 56, 19, 28, 18, 24, 14, 9}
Tr[data] (* check data points sum to n *)
LogLikelihood[MultinomialDistribution[n, pj], {data}]
```

Does not working as expected?

I have checked

```
data = RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[n, pj]]
```

> MultinomialDistribution::vprobprm: "The value {0.567834,0.0502306,0.0292996,0.0237149,<<21>>,0.0263614,0.040333,0.239272} at position 2 in MultinomialDistribution[171,{0.567834,0.0502306,0.0292996,<<21>>,<<21>>,0.0263614,0.040333,0.239272}] is expected to be a list of numbers greater than or equal to 0 and summing to 1."

Why is this? I have checked that `Tr[pj]` is 1.

Win 7 MMA 10.0.2 X64[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize the coefficients:

```
pjj = Normalize[pj, Total];
data = {{3, 56, 19, 28, 18, 24, 14, 9}};
LogLikelihood[MultinomialDistribution[n, pjj], data]
(* -252.89 *)
```

Comment: I thought that MMA is smart enough to `Normalize` it automatically by now.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it can be a useful first step in figuring out what's going on in these situations to check if your distribution is valid, using the `DistributionParameterQ`:

```
DistributionParameterQ@MultinomialDistribution[n, pj]

(*
MultinomialDistribution::vprobprm: The value {0.567834,0.0502306,0.0292996,0.0237149,0.0229541,0.0263614,0.040333,0.239272} at position 2 in MultinomialDistribution[171,{0.567834,0.0502306,0.0292996,0.0237149,0.0229541,0.0263614,0.040333,0.239272}] is expected to be a list of numbers greater than or equal to 0 and summing to 1. >>

False *)
```

Comment: The problem was that `Tr[pj]` says it's 1. Mathematica is inconsistent.